# Bootstrap center text in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I simply want to center text in a div.
I've found center-block to no avail, 
also text-align to no avail...

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <span style="background:black; color:white">
            Ad Analytics and Attribution.
            </span>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="center-block">
            <span style="background:black; color:white">
            Addressable Audiences.
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <span style="background:black; color:white">
             Affiliate Apps.
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `class="text-center"` -- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Answer (score 0):

Use .text-center for span to make the text center

**[Reference URL](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)**